# Getting links from a web page using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to scrape a webpage for links of articles.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string html = web.DownloadString("http://www.dailymirror.lk");
    MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<a href=""(.+?)""/s*class=""panel-heading"">",RegexOptions.Singleline);

    foreach(Match m in m1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

The html markup that I am focused on in the page is this:

```
<a href="http://www.dailymirror.lk/99833/ravi-s-budget-blues" class="panel-heading">
```

However, my code is unable to retrieve the link, is there anyway I could revamp my code?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to scrape HTML with Regex. Use a proper library such as [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :)

Comment: @IanP -- somebody was going to paste that link.  I think it is mandatory.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments above, parsing html with a regular expression is generally a bad idea.

One approach is to use the HTML Agility Pack:

https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.mywebsite.com");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    // do something with link here
}
```